# Getting “DDL statements are not allowed in transactions ” error when re-index programmatically in magento 2.2.X

Tags: magento2, reindex, magento2.2

I am working on Magento 2.2.6. As per requirement I need to do re-index on **sales_order_save_after**  event.

It is working well in Magento 2.1.X but I am getting following error on Magento 2.2.X.

> Error: CRITICAL: User Error: DDL statements are not allowed in
>   transactions in vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on
>   line 504

Can anyone help me on the same ? I have to re-index after order complete as I need to display that order in my custom front-end page. Without re-index it is not displaying.